# Regex expression to find all paths in a HTML string

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a string, with a htmlentities encoded HTML code.

What I want to do is find **all** the paths in the document, between:

href="XXX", src="XXX".

I do have a regex expression that find all the links starting by http, https, ftp and file, and lest me iterate over it:

```
"/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why not trying finding everything between `href="` and the next `"`? It would be *much* easier and *less* error prone.

Comment: What about `href="([^" ]*)"`? Is " allowed in a URL? I think spaces are, actually...

Comment: @P O'Conbhui: spaces aren't allowed, as well as `"` character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: Doing it with a regex isn't reliable. The src=".." or href=".." statement can be part of a comment or a javascript statement. To reliable obtain the links I would suggest to use XPath:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782334/regex-expression-to-find-all-paths-in-a-html-string/14782594#14782594');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $selector->query('//a/@href | //@src');
foreach($result as $link) {
    echo $link->value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

If using a regex I would try to grab the content between the = `"` of the href or src attribute. Here comes an example how to get the links from *this* page using a regex:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782334/regex-expression-to-find-all-paths-in-a-html-string');

preg_match_all('/href="(?P<href>.*)"|src="(?P<src>.*)"/U', $html, $m);
                                                        <--- note the U to make the 
                                                             pattern ungreedy
var_dump($m['href']);
var_dump($m['src']);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the DOM to find all links in specific tags. For example to get urls from anchor tags do something like this (untested, but it should point you in the right direction):

```
function findPaths($url)
{
   $dom = new DOMDocument();

   //$url of page to search, the "@' is there to suppress warnings
   @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url) 

   $paths = array();
   foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $path)
   {
     $paths[] = array('url' => $path->getAttribute('href'), text => $path->nodeValue);
   }
   return $paths;
}
```

You could make it even easier using XPath to load and evaluate the DOM.